# Is there shortcut in DBeaver to cut line without selecting it like that of SQL management studio with ctrl+x indide query editor?

Tags: dbeaver

Is there shortcut in DBeaver to cut line without selecting it like that of SQL management studio with ctrl+x.

I mean if we want to cut whole line without selecting than how we can achieve it in DBeaver. in SQL management studio we do it with ctrl + x pressing in query editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ctrl + space in and it will work somehow similar to ctrl + x in MSSQL.
more shortcuts you can check here
***https://defkey.com/dbeaver-shortcuts***